# Filter function with multiple variables google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-custom-function

[image]

I want to be able to use a filter function for people in NAME whose P DATE  is within a specified range. However, if they have a Y under VALIDATED, I want the filter to **also** include names with the T DATE that meets the same specified range.

This is my ignorant attempt at trying to do this but it, of course, creates an Error.

```
=FILTER(A2:D6,C2:C6 <B10+D2:D6,"Y",B2:B6<B10)
```

Apologies if this is too easy to be asking; I've be reading for over 3 hours and haven't found how to do this or if this can be done.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Filters values in `A2:A6` if *either*  condition is true:

```
=FILTER(A2:A6,
   (B2:B6<B10)+ 
   ((C2:C6<B10)*(D2:D6="Y")))
```

In the FILTER function conditions:

- `+` is equivalent to `OR`
- `*` is equivalent to `AND`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `FILTER` you can use the `QUERY` function as in this formula:

```
=QUERY(A2:D6,"SELECT A WHERE D='Y' AND C <= date '"&TEXT(B10,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'")
```

By referencing the cell `B10`, you can change the date in it to any date you like and it will be picked in the formula.

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en-GB)
- [`TEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en-GB)